# PSU started to make a smell

Tags: power-supply

It smells a little bit like melted plastic, but its functioning perfectly well right now and I can't see any problems having inspected it. Would you replace immediately with this kind of thing? or just keep an eye on it?

Comment: How old is it...?

Comment: Its 18 months old, unbranded.

Answer (score 5):

I would definitely order a new one, and if you can't live without your computer in the meantime - just keep an eye on it, and never leave it powered on and unattended.

It might also be a good idea to switch it off and have a visual inspection to look for signs of damage.

Disclaimer: I am not a fireman, electrician or hardware engineer!

Comment: Yep - definitely sounds like it's on the way out. The added benefit of a visual inspection is that you can take the opportunity to make a note of all the number (power rating etc.) to ensure you buy a suitable replacement.

Comment: new acronym...IANAFEOHE

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not a fireman either, think I'll order a new one..

Comment: "Disclaimer: I am not a fireman, electrician or hardware engineer!"  or psychopath?

Answer (score 2):

Considering that it is not new (the first days/weeks a strange smell is normal) I suggest to looking for a new PSU.

I would suggest to not look at the data of your old PSU but make a list of the component (models) you have mounted on your PC and only **THEN** decide the characteristics of your new PSU.

If you need help just post your components and we can help choosing the correct one for your needs.

And an additional thing, if you like your PC **don't buy OEM** PSU but buy good quality ones.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on kind of smell.

Sometimes new boards are smelling new.
Sometimes old boards are smelling like melting dust.
Sometimes PSU boards are smelling because some circuit parts are going away.

But you have to find out the reason!

Answer (score 1):

If it is brand new and making the smell, I wouldn't worry about it if it went away after a few days.  If it has been in use, I would promptly stop using it and remove the PSU.  Just because it seems like it's working, doesn't mean it isn't starting to fail.  Be thankful it warned you before it fried the rest of the computer.